# Annihilators of a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Proof: Ann(a) + Ann(b) = Ann(ab)

Answer: Ann(a) + Ann(b) ⊆ Ann(ab) and for the reverse inclusion I said since a ∈ ab and b ∈ ab then
Ann(a) + Ann(b) ⊇ Ann(ab), hence Ann(a) + Ann(b) = Ann(ab). Is it true, if not where is the catch and can I be corrected, thanks in advance.

Comment: The notion $a\in ab$ doesn't make any sense. What is $a, b$? Are these some elements of the ring?

Comment: Tagging this question [general-topology] seems like a pretty foolish thing to do. I suppose you could have come across this in a general-topology context, but even so such a tag 1) doesn't attract the right subject matter attention 2) might be construed as being a little trollish.

Comment: Sorry chief, I have never used this site before I didn't know which procedures to follow when asking Q's and sorry I forgot to mention that all the elements comes from a commutative ring R, but anyhow I got the answer, I will try to be clear and meaningful next time when I need help. Thanks for the motivation, cheers

Answer (score 2):

No. While the first containment is true (although you did not give anything in the way of a proof) the other containment cannot be proven. There are counterexamples.

For example, in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^3)$, $ann(x)=(x^2)$ and $ann(x^2)=(x)$, and $ann(x)=ann(x)+ann(x)\subsetneq ann(x^2)$.

It's difficult to offer advice on what you wrote because it is both too short and not meaningful. Specifically the expression "$a\in ab$" doesn't have any obvious meaning. If you can explain more about what you meant, I can elaborate more.

Comment: Sorry chief, I have never used this site before I didn't know which procedures to follow when asking Q's and sorry I forgot to mention that all the elements comes from a commutative ring R, but anyhow I got the answer, I will try to be clear and meaningful next time when I need help. Thanks for the motivation, cheers